# Not able to DataBound the `Style` attribute in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, styles, html

Not able to DataBound the `Style` attribute

```
Style='<%# Eval("LeftPadding","padding-left:{0}") %>'
```

**Full Code**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Report Item" SortExpression="ReportItem">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label Style='<%# Eval("LeftPadding","padding-left:{0}") %>' ID="lblReportItem"
            runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Caption") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Width="350px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

But I can DataBound some other attributes even not a Standard HTML attribute, like below

```
<asp:Label StyleTemp='<%# Eval("LeftPadding","padding-left:{0}") %>' ID="lblReportItem"
                runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Caption") %>'></asp:Label>
```

**What is the problem with `Style` ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got Answer :)

```
<asp:Label Style=<%# string.Format("padding-left:{0}px",Eval("LeftPadding")!=DBNull.Value? Convert.ToString(Eval("LeftPadding")): "0") %>
                                                            ID="lblReportItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Caption") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Tried by without giving the Single Quotes for the `style` attribute and used `string.Format`

```
Style=<%# string.Format("padding-left:{0}px",Eval("LeftPadding")!=DBNull.Value? Convert.ToString(Eval("LeftPadding")): "0") %>
```